# Bevyengine Panic on despawn

Tags: multithreading, rust, panic, bevy

I use bevy 0.6 and rapierphysics_2d 0.12.0
I have panic as a result of clearing my scene. I have two functions below::

```
fn cleanup_player(mut commands: Commands, player_data: Res<PlayerData>, query: Query<Entity>) {
  commands
      .entity(player_data.player_entity)
      .despawn_recursive();
  commands
      .entity(player_data.camera_entity)
      .despawn_recursive();
}

fn cleanup(mut commands: Commands, query: Query<Entity>) {
  for entity in query.iter() {
      commands.entity(entity).despawn_recursive();
  }
}
```

As you can see they are just despawn created earlier entities. But it causes a panic if I use any of it.

I'm actually trying to invoke them on changing from InGame to MainMenu(by pressing ESC)

```
impl Plugin for PugPlugin {
    fn build(&self, app: &mut App) {
        app.add_plugin(RapierPhysicsPlugin::<NoUserData>::default())
        .add_system(camera_follow_player.label("Camera system"))
            .add_system_set(
                SystemSet::on_enter(crate::AppState::InGame)
                    .with_system(sprite_spawn)
                    .with_system(spawn_floor),
            )
            .add_system_set(
                SystemSet::on_update(crate::AppState::InGame)
                    .with_system(check_delete)
                    .with_system(myphysics::player_jumps.label("Player Jumps System"))
                    .with_system(myphysics::jump_reset.label("Jump Reset System"))
                    .with_system(myphysics::player_movement.label("Player Movement System"))
                    .with_system(death_by_height.label("Death system"))
                    ,
            )
             .add_system_set(SystemSet::on_exit(AppState::InGame).with_system(cleanup).with_system(cleanup_player))
            ;
    }
}
```

You can see the system set at the end. So I want to switch to main menu from InGame Set, it's not working.

P.s just clean function is also not working inside a scene even without any transitions to MainMenu or smth. So I can't even just delete any entity from my game.

```
thread 'Compute Task Pool (0)' panicked at 'Attempting to create an EntityCommands for entity 1v1, which doesn't exist.', /Users/Alexander/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/bevy_rapier2d-0.12.0/src/physics/resources.rs:240:26
```

https://github.com/asinchenko/NamiWorld

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that was a problem with my rapier2d physics plugin!

```
cargo update -p bevy_rapier2d
```

update from 0.12.0 to 0.12.1 solved my problem